# How to make an one-to-one merge on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say `df1` looks like:

```
id  x
a   1
b   2
b   3
c   4
```

and `df2` looks like:

```
id  y
b   9
b   8
```

How do I merge them so that the output is:

```
id  x  y
b   2  9
b   3  8
```

I've tried `pd.merge(df1, df2, on='id')` but it is giving me:

```
id  x   y
b   2   9
b   2   8
b   3   9
b   3   8
```

which is not what I want.

Comment: I think It isn't dupe

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, [`GroupBy.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) + `merge`

```
new_df = (df1.assign(count=df1.groupby('id').cumcount())
             .merge(df2.assign(count=df2.groupby('id').cumcount()),
                     on=['id', 'count'], how='inner')
             .drop(columns='count'))

  id  x  y
0  b  2  9
1  b  3  8
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not know the magic of groupby + cumcount(). This is exactly what I need